# how to have multiple parameter preset?

Tags: animation

I create a particle simulation and i want to have different setting for lot of parameter including the forces (turbulance,wind etc) so i can compare them. The only thing i know if i'm using keyframe (animation), i can easily use action editor to have different animation set. But action editor won't work without keyframes/animation. How to solve this ? i can actually copy the whole objects into another layer so i can have different setting, but is there any other simple method ? i like the idea using action editor, so like to have set of different parameters value for the same object.

Anyone know ?

Comment: You can easily keyframe those parameters by right clicking>add keyframe... I don't see any other problem?